# Object around user permissions dictionary

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to expose `permissions` property on ORM `User` model:

```
PERMISSIONS_MAP= {
    'admin': ['can_delete'],
}

class DatabaseModel:
    pass

class User(DatabaseModel):
    def __init__(self, role):
        self.role = role
    
    @property
    def permissions(self):
        return role_permissions.list(self.role)

class RolePermissions:
    def __init__(self, permissions_map: dict = PERMISSIONS_MAP):
        self.permissions_map = permissions_map

    def list(self, role):
        print(f'listing permissions')
        return [p for p in self.permissions_map.get(role, [])]

role_permissions = RolePermissions()

admin = User('admin')
assert admin.permissions == ['can_delete']
assert admin.permissions == ['can_delete'] # here the permissions will be recalculated, but ideally shouldn't

guest = User('guest')
assert guest.permissions == []
```

But I don't like 2 things:

1. Return value of `permissions` property will be calculated each time the property is called:

I can easily alleviate that by switching `property` with `functools.cached_property` decorator.

However, I would like to instead improve the design. Would changing to `RolePermissions(self.role).list()` from `role_permissions.list(self.role)` be a move into a right direction? Where do I go from there to mitigate unwanted recalculations?

2. `User` class is coupled to `user_permissions`. I could solve it through dependency injection, yet it feels cumbersome to make the `permissions` property accept `UserPermissions` object. Is there a better way to decouple this?

Any other suggestions are of course welcome!

Comment: Does this use SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @Reinderien: nope, Mongoengine, a wrapper around pymongo(MongoDB). It is similar however (was modeled after DjangoORM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PERMISSIONS_MAP` should probably be a map of enums to enum sets, not strings to string lists. Stringly-typed data are not a good idea.

Add PEP484 type hints to your function signatures.

`permissions` being a property is fine. You're concerned about recalculation, but

1. once this code is refactored and the list comprehension goes away, the amount of "recalculation" will be trivial, and
2. whereas you could add an `lru_cache`, that is not called-for here.

Do not use mutable structures like dictionaries for argument defaults. Usual workaround is to default to `None` and then fill in with a dictionary in function body.

Do not call a method `list` since that's a built-in.

Your list comprehension should go away. You can just delete the entire `RolePermissions` class, and in `User`,

```
@property
def permissions(self) -> set[Permission]:
    return PERMISSIONS_MAP[self.role]
```

The `get` is problematic because it hides a situation where a user has an invalid role not present in `PERMISSIONS_MAP`, so don't do that.

Comment: Thanks! I admit to oversimplifying my example, in a more complete version `USER_PERMISSIONS` is indeed a mapping of enums, hence the list comprehension (it extracts enum values). So if I decided to keep the `RolePermissions` class (as a wrapper for the mapping with `as_list` method exposed), do you have any opinion on point 2. in my question? How can I (should I?) get rid of the coupling between `role_permissions` and `User`?

Comment: I don't see that coupling as much of a concern. More concerning are lack of type hints, and a singleton permissions class that doesn't deserve to be a class.